# Is it possible to code html blocks with triangle shape and content?

Tags: html, css, markup

A designer with whom i used to work have sent me an concept of website design.

Here's a part page containing a list of posts - [image: list of blocks]

As i see the most part of those pink polygones is just a background and some triangles and rhombuses can contain short text (I masked it by gray brush) titles and sometimes icons.

I wonder is there a way to do it in html/css/js without flash?

Comment: you can use `canvas` or `svg` in `html5`

Comment: This may help you [CSS3 Shapes](http://www.css3shapes.com/)

Comment: could probably do it with just css and images, too. depends on your needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use dynamicHtml has javascript. Example site : http://trickyscripter.com/examples/after/jsgraphics_e.htm

Some javascript libraries are quite good : give a try at : http://raphaeljs.com/

You can use html5 Canvas : Example site : http://www.williammalone.com/articles/html5-canvas-example/

You can create a huge texture.png shaped has a diamond and align it left or right. (favorite)

Keep in mind that 'blocks' are blocks.

Answer (score 1):

This can be accomplished in a legacy-browser-friendly way using some (mildy cumbersome) CSS blocking...

http://jsfiddle.net/AuZ5H/2

```
.wrapper {
    background-color: #eee;
    width: 250px;
    height: 225px;
    font-size: 8px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.block {
    float: right;
    clear: right;
    background-color: #ddd;
    height: 25px;
}
.block1 {
    width: 200px;
}
.block2 {
    width: 150px;
}
.block3 {
    width: 100px;
}
.block4 {
    width: 50px;
}
.block5 {
    width: 1px;
}

<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="block block1"></div>
    <div class="block block2"></div>
    <div class="block block3"></div>
    <div class="block block4"></div>
    <div class="block block5"></div>
    <div class="block block4"></div>
    <div class="block block3"></div>
    <div class="block block2"></div>
    <div class="block block1"></div>
    Content here.
</div>
```

Obviously the more blocks you use, with each having smaller heights, the more granular the layout. You'd need to double and reverse the blocks for your rhombuses (rhombii?).